# Retention of non-static variable value inside a function accessed by multiple tasks

Tags: c, multithreading, task

I have a function defined:

```
int32_t function(const bool inDebugPattern)
{
  char tempBuff[256]; memset(tempBuff, 0, sizeof tempBuff);

  /* use tempBuff[] */
}
```

which is called by multiple tasks, will the memory allocation of `tempBuff[]` be separate(unique) for each call of this function or will it be shared and can be corrupted by a concurrent call from other tasks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since tempBuff is a local variable it will be unique for each function call

Take a look at [C Scope rules](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm)